# Comparing own elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, methods, compare

I want to comparing elements in an array.  For each element, starting from left to right, find the first next integer (y) with a value greater than the existing one (x), then find the next first integer (z) with a value smaller than y(left to right) integer of it.  If next greater and smaller are not -1, print (y - z) to the console, else print-1. My code like this. But my array 2, 4, 1, 5, 6 and my output -6, -6, -6, -6, -1. Or my array 4, 3, 8, 2, 1 but my output is -1,-1, -1, -2, -1.

In your solution my inputs 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1 and my outputs 0, 5, -1, -1, 4, 0,0 but my outputs must be for 4: y = 8 and z = 3 so y - z = `5` and for 6: is **same**, for 8 there isn't greater and y= -1, z= -1 so return `-1`, for 3: y = 5 and z = 1 so y - z = `4` return `4` for `2` is same. Hence, for the array {4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1} I expected the output {5, 5, -1, 4, 4, -1, -1}.

```
public static int[] comparator(int[] arr) {
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int[] answers = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            
            if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                y = arr[j];
                if(y>arr[j]) {
                    z = arr[j];
                    break;
                }
                answers[i] = z-y;
            }
            else answers[i] = -1;
            
        }
        
    }
    return answers;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
public static int[] comparator(int[] arr) {
        int[] answers = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            int x = arr[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; !found && j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                int y = arr[j];
                if( x < y){
                    for (int w = j + 1; !found && w < arr.length; w++){
                        int z = arr[j + 1];
                        if (y > z) {
                           answers[i] = (y != -1 && z != -1) ?  y - z : -1;
                           found = true;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!found)
                answers[i] = -1;
        }
        return answers;
    }
```

> For each element, starting from left to right,

```
 for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++)
```

> find the first next integer (y) with a value greater than the existing one (x)

```
        for (int j = i + 1; !found && j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            int y = arr[j];
            if( x < y){
```

> then find the next first integer (z) with a value smaller than y(left to right) integer of it.

```
                    for (int w = j + 1; !found && w < arr.length; w++){
                        int z = arr[j + 1];
                        if (y > z) {
```

> if next greater and smaller are not -1, print (y - z) to the console, else print-1.

```
                           answers[i] = (y != -1 && z != -1) ?  y - z : -1;
                           found = true;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!found)
                answers[i] = -1;
```

The code be simplified to:

```
public static int[] comparator(int[] arr) {
    int[] answers = Arrays.stream(arr).map(i -> -1).toArray();
    for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++)
            if (arr[i] < arr[j] && isElementFound(arr, answers, i, j))
                break;
    return answers;
}

private static boolean isElementFound(int[] arr, int[] answers, int i, int j) {
    for (int w = j + 1; w < arr.length; w++)
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            answers[i] = (arr[j] != -1 && arr[j + 1] != -1) ? arr[j] - arr[j + 1] : -1;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

and testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{ 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(comparator(arr)));
    int[] arr2 = new int[] { 4, 3, 8, 2, 1 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(comparator(arr2)));
}
```

Comment: In your solution my inputs 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1 and my outputs 0, 5, -1, -1, 4, 0,0 but my outputs must be for 4: y = 8 and z = 3 so y - z = 5 and for 6: is same, for 8 there isn't greater and y= -1, z= -1 so return -1, for 3: y = 5 and z = 1 so y - z = 4 return 4 for 2 is same. According to your other solution my outputs 5 and 4. I hope I can explain what I want.

Comment: For the array 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5 which array do you want back?

Comment: for 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 5, 1; I want back 5, 5, -1, 4, 4, -1, -1